# how to get mx record for domain

Tags: php

I wanna get details of mx record...but I don't know how to get mx record target in my code...
I get details of mx records. How can I display mx target in my code...
Using PHP, ping an SMTP server and check MX records? I'm willing to write a script such :

my code is :

```
  // Queries the DNS server for MX entries of a certain domain.
protected function mx_query($domain) {
    $hosts = array();
    $weight = array();
    if (function_exists('getmxrr')) {
        getmxrr($domain, $hosts, $weight);
    } else {
        $this->getmxrr($domain, $hosts, $weight);
    }
    return array($hosts, $weight);
}

// Provides a windows replacement for the getmxrr function.
protected function getmxrr($hostname, &$mxhosts, &$mxweights) {
    if (!is_array($mxhosts)) {
        $mxhosts = array();
    }
    if (!is_array($mxweights)) {
        $mxweights = array();
    }
    if (empty($hostname)) {
        return;
    }
    $cmd = 'nslookup -type=MX ' . escapeshellarg($hostname);
    if (!empty($this->mx_query_ns)) {
        $cmd .= ' ' . escapeshellarg($this->mx_query_ns);
    }
    exec($cmd, $output);
    if (empty($output)) {
        return;
    }
    $i = -1;
    foreach ($output as $line) {
        $i++;
        if (preg_match("/^$hostname\tMX preference = ([0-9]+), mail exchanger = (.+)$/i", $line, $parts)) {
            $mxweights[$i] = trim($parts[1]);
            $mxhosts[$i] = trim($parts[2]);
        }
        if (preg_match('/responsible mail addr = (.+)$/i', $line, $parts)) {
            $mxweights[$i] = $i;
            $mxhosts[$i] = trim($parts[1]);
        }
    }
    return ($i != -1);
}

        if($this->check_mx){
        $check_mx = $this->check_mx($domain);
        if(!$check_mx){
            $output['result']['errors']['check_mx'] = 'Domain failed MX check.';
            $output['result']['success'] = 0;
        }else{
            $output['result']['report']['check_mx'] = $output['result']['report']['target'];


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the PHP `dns_get_record` (and `dns_get_mx`) methods (and the given examples on the [documentation pages](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php)).